# How to include an additional claims to the id_token when using OpenID Connect with active directory federation services(ADFS)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, openid-connect

I have SaaS application being supported openid connect authentication via active directory federation services. Everything works fine. However, by default application receives only a fixed set of claims available in the id_token. So how can i include an additional claims to the id_token?

Answer (score 0):

Using AD FS 2016, I have done this following [Microsoft's documentation to customize claims to be emitted in id_token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/custom-id-tokens-in-ad-fs).

Comment: The article says "Create the Application Group in AD FS 2016" but application group has already been added after following this instruction - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/adfs. So now i have a configured resource partner and test account partner with the added claims provider trust and relying party trust respectively. Does that mean that including additional claims to the id_token requires adding another application group? And if so should i add new application group to the account partner computer or resource partner one?